# Maven command need to skip download dependencies

Tags: shell, maven, command-line, command

I have a maven project where in it downloads dependencies after every 12 hours if i try to do mvn test. Is there any i can skip downloading dependencies if the file already exists. My intention is to reduce the time taken and reduce the network bandwidth usage.

Comment: Please share your settings.xml file.

Answer (score 10):

you can use -o switch to run your maven command in offline mode

Answer (score 0):

maven would only download dependencies if they are not in the local repository.
when running on your local pc the local repository is in your pc (in windows in the user home .m2 directory).
so either that directory gets deleted OR you changed the version of the dependencies OR you are using SNAPSHOT versions which means it is always trying to get the latest version from remote repository and thats actually something you shouldn't do (always use hardcoded version number of a release and not a dev build).